# Install pandoc and update a docker container for Shiny - Rmarkdown

Tags: r, docker, shiny

I have a Shiny app and I added feature for rendering rmarkdown. I'm getting this error when I try to render rmarkdown:

```
Warning: Error in : pandoc version 1.12.3 or higher is required and was not found (see the help page ?rmarkdown::pandoc_available).
```

I tried to add this into my dockerfile but it didn't work.

```
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y pandoc
```

And this is my dockerfile:

```
FROM my-profile/appname:version

COPY shiny-app /app

EXPOSE 3838

# run app on container start
CMD ["R", "-e", "shiny::runApp('/app', host = '0.0.0.0', port = 3838)"]
```

How can I install correctly Pandoc in my existent app.
(I'm using Mac M1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's about docker base image.

I had `amd64/r-base` docker image and couldn't install pandoc. I created my app with `rocker/r-ver` and added `RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y pandoc` into my dockerfile it's solved the issue.

My dockerfile

```
# Base image https://hub.docker.com/u/rocker/
FROM rocker/r-ver:4.3.0

# system libraries of general use
## install debian packages

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get upgrade -y && \
    apt-get install -y \
    libcurl4-openssl-dev \
    libssl-dev \
    libxml2-dev \
    zlib1g-dev \
    libfontconfig1-dev \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    libpng-dev \
    libtiff5-dev \
    libjpeg-dev \
    libharfbuzz-dev \
    libfribidi-dev \
    libpq-dev \
    && apt-get clean

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libgit2-dev
# Install GDAL dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y gdal-bin libgdal-dev

# Set GDAL configuration
ENV GDAL_CONFIG=/usr/bin/gdal-config

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libudunits2-dev

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y pandoc


# copy necessary files
## renv.lock file
COPY /shiny-app/renv.lock ./renv.lock
## app folder
COPY /shiny-app ./app


# Set the working directory to the app folder
WORKDIR /app

# Run the install_packages.R script
RUN Rscript install_packages.R

# expose port
EXPOSE 3838

# run app on container start
CMD ["R", "-e", "shiny::runApp('/app', host = '0.0.0.0', port = 3838)"]
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using the [`pandoc`](https://cderv.github.io/pandoc/articles/pandoc.html) package? This is just a guess at what you need to include in the docker, I haven't actually tried it:

```
RUN R -e "install.packages('pandoc')"
RUN R -e "install.packages('gh')"
RUN R -e "pandoc_install()"
```

Comment: I tried this(I added first 2 line to dockerfile), I created an R script 
library(pandoc);pandoc_install("3.1.1") . When I run that script and " ```✔ Pandoc version 3.1.1 installed.
✔ Version '3.1.1' is now the active one.
Killed
Warning in system(paste(shQuote(path), "--version"), intern = TRUE) :
  running command ''/root/.local/share/r-pandoc/3.1.1/pandoc' --version' had status 137``` I'm getting this

Comment: why not the third line too?